# laravel pass validation error to custom view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a validation but cant show it on view, its important to return search view and don't redirect back user. help me please, thanks all?

Controller :

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $msg = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'search' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($msg->fails()) {
        return view('layouts.search')->withErrors($msg->messages());
    } else {
        return "Thank you!";
    }
}
```

View :

```
@if($errors->any())
   <ul class="alert alert-danger">
      @foreach($errors as $error)
         <li> {{$error}} </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
@else
```

Comment: Please make sure that $msg->messages() is not null

Comment: @ParthVora Yep Is Not Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$error->first('name_of_error_field')` to show error messages.

You can do it like this:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'search' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('layouts.search')->withErrors($validator); // <----- Send the validator here
    } else {
        return "Thank you!";
    }
}
```

And in view:

```
@if($errors->any())
   <ul class="alert alert-danger">
      @foreach($errors as $error)
         <li> {{$error->first('name_of_error_field')}} </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
@endif
```

> See more about [Laravel Custom Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't Work !!

Comment: You should specify name of the field inside `first()` method. See the updated code above.

Comment: I now but when i have dd($errors) in foreach is blank ! but out of foreach have errors ...

Comment: Just don't use `$validator->messages()` inside `withErrors()`, use `$validator` instead

Comment: Thank You Sooo Mutch Men

Comment: @MortezaNegahi  - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!